# Why does CLAT in 464XLAT architecture use Stateless NAT64 instead of Stateful?

Tags: nat, ipv6, networking

As of my understanding, stateless NAT is using 1:1 translation, meaning it needs one IPv4 address for one IPv6 address vice versa, thus not preserving IPv4. Since the CLAT is supposed to be router/gateway for the local network, meaning the *local* side of CLAT is private IPv4 address (RFC1918),but as of my understanding  IPv4-embedded IPv6 containing private IPv4 address is supposed to be dropped either by the receiver or the intermediate party (NAT64 translator).

Why does CLAT use Stateless NAT64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as of my understanding IPv4-embedded IPv6 containing private IPv4
> address is supposed to be dropped either by the receiver or the
> intermediate party (NAT64 translator)

That is only true of using the well-known prefix (`64:ff9b::/96`):

> **[3.1.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6052#section-3.1) Restrictions on the Use of the Well-Known Prefix**
>
> The Well-Known Prefix MUST NOT be used to represent non-global IPv4
> addresses, such as those defined in [[RFC1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918)] or listed in [Section 3
> of [RFC5735]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735#section-3). Address translators MUST NOT translate packets in which
> an address is composed of the Well-Known Prefix and a non- global IPv4
> address; they MUST drop these packets.

The well-known prefix is not the only prefix that can be used (see my highlights in the paragraph below the figure):

> **[2.2.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6052#section-2.2) IPv4-Embedded IPv6 Address Format**
>
> IPv4-converted IPv6 addresses and IPv4-translatable IPv6 addresses
> follow the same format, described here as the IPv4-embedded IPv6
> address Format. IPv4-embedded IPv6 addresses are composed of a
> variable-length prefix, the embedded IPv4 address, and a variable-
> length suffix, as presented in the following diagram, in which PL
> designates the prefix length:
>
> ```
> +--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
> |PL| 0-------------32--40--48--56--64--72--80--88--96--104---------|
> +--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
> |32|     prefix    |v4(32)         | u | suffix                    |
> +--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
> |40|     prefix        |v4(24)     | u |(8)| suffix                |
> +--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
> |48|     prefix            |v4(16) | u | (16)  | suffix            |
> +--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
> |56|     prefix                |(8)| u |  v4(24)   | suffix        |
> +--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
> |64|     prefix                    | u |   v4(32)      | suffix    |
> +--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
> |96|     prefix                                    |    v4(32)     |
> +--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
>
>                              Figure 1
> ```
>
> In these addresses, the prefix shall be either the "Well-Known Prefix"
> ***or a "Network-Specific Prefix" unique to the organization deploying
> the address translators.*** The prefixes can only have one of the
> following lengths: 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, or 96. (The Well-Known Prefix
> is 96 bits long, and can only be used in the last form of the table.)

Comment: So its ok to forward private IPv4 address in NAT64. Then how about the receiving end? I mean some server won't serve  RFC1918 address right?

Comment: No, NAT64 is something else. Your question is about XLAT464, which is different.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I mean XLAT464.

Comment: See [Section 4.1 of RFC 6877, 464XLAT: Combination of Stateful and Stateless Translation](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6877#section-4.1). It explains how the IPv4 host has a Private IPv4 address.